# How do you get hold of an Android Context for a Junit test from a Java Project?

Tags: android, android-context

I need to access and Android context for a JUnit Test.

I have tried using MockContext and extending the AndroidTestCase but each time I get an error saying (stub!)

Answer (score 23):

What about using AndroidTestCase instead of a JUnit test? AndroidTestCase will provide a Context with getContext() that can be used where it's needed.

Comment: AndroidTestCase is now deprecated.

Comment: How to use it ?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to access context from JUnit **without extending** `AndroidTestCase` is to use `Rule` to launch an activity under test. Rules are interceptors which are executed for each test method and will run before any of your setup code in the `@Before` method. Rules were presented as a replacement for the `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class ConnectivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testIsConnected() throws Exception {
        Context context = mActivityRule.getActivity().getBaseContext();
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean connected = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
        Assert.assertEquals(connected, ConnectionUtils.isConnected(context));
    }
}
```

Comment: ActivityTestRule class does not exist

Comment: @kurdtpage sure it does https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule just make sure you have the support test library dependency

Comment: Here's the dependency I added to resolve the missing ActivityTestRule:      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

Answer (score 2):

If your test is an instrumentation test (running on emulator or device), you can simply use

```
Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
```

The dependency is:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for case when your test class extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("your.file");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("Error", "Error during file opening!!!");
}
```

Comment: Question is only about getting context not about opening File from assets folder.

Answer (score -1):

Each Activity is a subclass of Context, so you must use your Activities when you need Context. The class Context is not something you instantiate from an application.

Comment: Then use the getActivity() method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html#getActivity()