# Android assets used for testing

Tags: java, android, testing, android-assets

I have a CSV file that I want to make available for my Android testing suite. I don't want it to be available for the main app, though. I saved it in the `assets` folder of my test project. Then I try to access it from a test using

```
context.getAssets().open(DATA_ASSET);
```

where `DATA_ASSET` is declared as

```
DATA_ASSET = "cards.csv"
```

I set the `context` to refer to the Activity which I am testing. However, this obviously won't work as I have it since it will look in the assets of the main app. I see two possibilities to  fix this:

1. Provide the correct path to the asset installed with the test project
2. Obtain a `Context` which refers to the test project's resources and assets

I haven't found any way to do either of these yet. Perhaps there is a third solution that I haven't thought of. How can I access the assets that are installed with the test project?

Comment: It's not a clean fix if you're subclassing `AndroidTestCase`, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8870318/357055) might help you to get a `Context` for your test project.

Comment: @acj Mostly I'm subclassing `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, but some of my tests subclass `ActivityUnitTestCase` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get context of test project in Android junit test case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605611/get-context-of-test-project-in-android-junit-test-case)

Comment: @acj That looks like the solution I need. Thanks! I'll try it out to see if it works.

Comment: @acj Sweet! It seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're subclassing `InstrumentationTestCase` or a similar class, you can obtain a `Context` for the test project by doing the following:

```
Context ctx = getInstrumentation().getContext();
```