# Getting context in AndroidTestCase or InstrumentationTestCase in Android Studio's Unit Test feature

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I got some of my old tests running with Android Studio 1.1.0's new unit test support feature. 
When running gradlew testDebug the tests are run, but all of the tests that require a Context fail because `getContext` (AndroidTestCase) / `getInstrumentation.getContext()` (InstrumentationTestCase) both return null.

How can I solve this?

Here's two variants I've tried:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;

public class TestTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    Context context;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        context = getInstrumentation().getContext();

        assertNotNull(context);

    }

    public void testSomething() {

        assertEquals(false, true);
    }  

}
```

and

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

public class TestTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    Context context;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        context = getContext();

        assertNotNull(context);

    }

    public void testSomething() {

        assertEquals(false, true);
    }

}
```

This is my module's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.penistest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and here the `build.gradle` for the project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

EDIT: My tests all worked before upgrading to AS 1.1.0 and ran on a device / emulator.

EDIT:

Heres 2 screenshots of failing InstrumentationTestCase and AndroidTestCase:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to run similar tests, and it always return null for me. Are you implying your tests used to run before with the same code (with a previous version)?

Comment: Yes, those tests worked when run on a real device.

Comment: @Ascorbin Please try my answer, and test using the first two code snippets using `getInstrumentation().getContext()`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Will do.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Updated - Please use Espresso for writing instrumentation tests

## Newer Examples:

I got these **working without deploying** to a device. Put the **tests in the `/src/main/test/` folder.**

Here are newer examples, I took your examples and tested them in my own temporary test project. I ran the tests via command line: `./gradlew clean test`. Please read more here: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support.

Top `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

App `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    testOptions { // <-- You need this
        unitTests {
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' // <-- You need this
}
```

### Basic Tests:

`InstrumentationTestCaseTest` to test `Context` and `Assertions`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
import android.test.mock.MockContext;

public class InstrumentationTestCaseTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    Context context;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        context = new MockContext();

        assertNotNull(context);

    }

    public void testSomething() {

        assertEquals(false, true);
    }

}
```

`ActivityTestCase` to test your `Resources`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.test.ActivityTestCase;

public class ActivityTestCaseTest extends ActivityTestCase {

    public void testFoo() {

        Context testContext = getInstrumentation().getContext();
        Resources testRes = testContext.getResources();

        assertNotNull(testRes);
        assertNotNull(testRes.getString(R.string.app_name));
    }
}
```

`AndroidTestCase` to test `Context` and `Assertions`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.test.mock.MockContext;

public class AndroidTestCaseTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    Context context;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        context = new MockContext();

        setContext(context);

        assertNotNull(context);

    }

    // Fake failed test
    public void testSomething()  {
        assertEquals(false, true);
    }
}
```

## Googling Old Examples:

After Googling a lot bout this error, I believe your bet is to use `getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_res).` or something similar in order to test your resources.

### **Using InstrumentationTestCase:**

**Test Resources:**

```
public class PrintoutPullParserTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    public void testParsing() throws Exception {
        PrintoutPullParser parser = new PrintoutPullParser();
        parser.parse(getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().getXml(R.xml.printer_configuration));
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870318/950427 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16763196/950427

### **Using ActivityTestCase:**

**Test Resources:**

```
public class Test extends ActivityTestCase {

   public void testFoo() {  

      // .. test project environment
      Context testContext = getInstrumentation().getContext();
      Resources testRes = testContext.getResources();
      InputStream ts = testRes.openRawResource(R.raw.your_res);

      assertNotNull(testRes);
   }    
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820390/950427

### **Using AndroidTestCase:**

**Getting the `Context` (a simple hack):**

```
private Context getTestContext() {
    try {
        Method getTestContext = ServiceTestCase.class.getMethod("getTestContext");
        return (Context) getTestContext.invoke(this);
    } catch (final Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14232913/950427

But, if you look a the source code of `AndroidTestCase`, it looks like you need to set a `Context` yourself:

Source: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/test/AndroidTestCase.java.shtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73276/discussion-between-jared-burrows-and-ascorbin).

Comment: @Ascorbin http://wikisend.com/download/284136/AndroidTestProject_jaredsburrows.zip. `griddle clean test` or in Android Studio, File -> "Import Project" -> Click on the `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Ascorbin, the bounty ends in 10 hours, did you try the project I sent?

Comment: Yes I did, did not work. You sure have earned the bounty, thanks for your effort!

Comment: Nope, they didn't, failed exactly the same as mine. I have no idea what the reason could be, I'll probably wait for the next update on AS until I try to fix it again.

Comment: Do you have the latest update(Android Studio 1.1.0 Build 135.1470770)? I don't understand why it should matter if you also ran via command line: `gradlew clean test`. You are using the same versions of plugins as I am.

Comment: The link you provided (new test project) gives me a mp4 video instead of code

Comment: @Damnum That is very weird. I am removing that link. I have now deleted that source.

Comment: This is already deprecated. See latest response; it seems that is containing the latest method to get context.

Answer (score 20):

With the [Android Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html), you can

- get test apk context with `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`
- get app apk context with `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`
- get Instrumentation with `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()`

See the bottom of the linked page for how to add Testing Support library to your project.

Comment: So what's the difference between these contexts?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky there are two APKs installed when running Android tests. One which is the APK of your applications and second which is the APK of the tests. So therefore "app APK context" and "test APK context".

Answer (score 11):

Here is a recent way to setup (unit) instrumentation tests

## Setup

In your *build.gradle* add:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

and the following dependencies:

```
// Instrumentation tests
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:$supportTestRunnerVersion"
// To use assertThat syntax
androidTestImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:$assertJVersion"
```

## Example class

```
public class Example {

    public Object doSomething() {
        // Context is used here
    }

}
```

## Example test

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleTest {

    private Context context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // In case you need the context in your test
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    }

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
        Example example = new Example();
        assertThat(example.doSomething()).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

## Documentation

- [Building Instrumented Unit Tests | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, because it contains the latest correct method to get instrumentation data.

Comment: The API changed to
    Context context = androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 4):

I was receiving an error when trying to make calls to SQLite using @taynguyen answer, so instead of:

`InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`

I used:

`InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`

In order to get my target application context instead of the Instrumentation context.

Answer (score 1):

`Context` needs to refer to something that extends `Context` such as an `Activity` or `Application` class.

```
Context context = new Activity();
```

Another alternative is to use `Robolectric.Application`.

Comment: I have a similar issue and isn't the whole point of "AndroidTestCase" to be able to test an activity-less class/project?
To be clear: I have a library (activity less) I'm trying to test. It uses of the "Context" (passed as a parameter in the library constructor), so I shouldn't have to use any activity if I understand correctly.

Comment: While new Activity() of course gives me a Context, I can not access my resources (Strings, Assets) from it unfortunately.

Comment: I have found that I can access resources with `new Activity().getResources`.  I'm not sure if there is some aspect of my setup that is causing this to work for me and not for you.

Comment: Why not use `new MockContext()` from instrumentation package?

Comment: Good point. For some purposes, I have found you can also use `Mockito.mock(Context.class)`. The most appropriate choice will probably depend on what you are generally using in the rest of the test class.

Answer (score 1):

`getInstrumentation().getContext()` is now deprecated you should use this
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` 
you can find more details here 
 [androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924431/androidx-test-instrumentationregistry-is-deprecated)