# Android bug: how to stay on Android error page about "method not mocked"?

Tags: android, mocking

When "not mocked" error occurs, error message referencign the following page:

http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked

But this page has redirect to somewhere else so I have no time to read about an error. On the redirected page, although, an error is not covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can help you: [Unit testing on Android Studio: "not mocked" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100925/unit-testing-on-android-studio-not-mocked-error)

Text from your link(sorry, i can't set this post as a comment) :

> Note that when running tests from Gradle, we will execute tests for
>   every variant of your code (see here). This means that tests will end
>   up executing at least twice (once with the release build of your code,
>   once with the debug build of production code).
>
> "Method ... not mocked."
>
> The android.jar file that is used to run unit tests does not contain
>   any actual code - that is provided by the Android system image on real
>   devices. Instead, all methods throw exceptions (by default). This is
>   to make sure your unit tests only test your code and do not depend on
>   any particular behaviour of the Android platform (that you have not
>   explicitly mocked e.g. using Mockito). If that proves problematic, you
>   can add the snippet below to your build.gradle to change this
>   behavior:
>
> ```
> android {
>   // ...
>   testOptions { 
>     unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> We are aware that the default behavior is problematic when using
>   classes like Log or TextUtils and will evaluate possible solutions in
>   future releases.

Comment: Thanks but I wished they fix this

Comment: They wrote: "This page is obsolete." Maybe they think that error obsolete too =D

Comment: Do you write them? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Developer%20Documentation

Comment: Not yet. I am nt sure who's mistake is this. They can always scan SO for bugs.