# Sqlite junit test in android

Tags: android-sqlite, android-junit

I have a class called CallWcfTask that extended from `extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`. I have declared these fields:

```
private String _CiName;
private CallWcfCallBack wcfCallBack;
private SQLiteDatabase _Db;
private List<String[]> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
```

in doInBackground method I have fetched data from my service and i put data into `List<String[]>`.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {

        String s = EsupFactory.getConfigString(SETTING_ROOT_CI) + "GetCI";
        JSONObject jsonObj = HttpUtil.requestJson(s, HttpUtil.HttpMethod.Post,
                new JSONObject().put("PCiName", _CiName).toString());
        JSONArray jCiArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("GetCIResult");
        if (jCiArray != null || !jCiArray.isNull(0)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < jCiArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject tmpobj = jCiArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String TmpId = String.valueOf(tmpobj.getInt("Id"));
                    String TmpTitle = tmpobj.getString("Title");
                    infoList.add(new String[]{TmpId, TmpTitle});

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            insert(infoList);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and finally i have inserted into my db by invoking **insert method**.

```
    public boolean insert(List<String[]> infoList) {
    for (String[] value :
            infoList) {
        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put("ID", Integer.valueOf(value[0]));
        insertValues.put("Title", value[1]);
        long insert = _Db.insert(_CiName, null, insertValues);
        if(insert == -1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, I want to do unit test for insert method.I write blow test:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class CallWcfTaskTest extends TestCase {
CallWcfTask wcfTask;
List<String[]> strings;

@Before
public void onCreate() {
    System.out.println("Test Started");
    strings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        String[] testlist = {i+"", "ali"+i};
        strings.add(testlist);
    }
    wcfTask = new CallWcfTask();
}

@Test
public void insertTest() {
    assertEquals(true,wcfTask.insert(strings));

}
}
```

but when I am running this test,I got this error:

```
    Test Started
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.safarayaneh.engineer.task.CallWcfTask.insert(CallWcfTask.java:79)
at com.safarayaneh.engineer.task.CallWcfTaskTest.insertTest(CallWcfTaskTest.java:33)
```

into my insert method, i am working with `SQLiteDatabase _Db`. how could i test my method in my scenario?

***************** **Edit** *****************

I have opened my db from ClsCI class constructor:

```
    public ClsCI(String pCiName, Context pcontext) {
    datasource = new DataSource(pcontext);
    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(pcontext);
    _Db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    _CiName = pCiName;
    _Context = pcontext;
}
```

and i have executed CallWcfTask from this class and I have passed this _Db as a parameter to my task.

Comment: You don't appear to be opening the database anywhere, so _Db will been null, as it's only be declared.

Comment: I have to open db into CallWcfTask class or test class?If i open db into CallWcfTask class, does it open into test class?

Comment: It has to be opened for at least the insert method, that's where it would be failing.

Comment: @MikeT I updated my post.

Comment: That may move you forward the result was?

Comment: if i right understand, into not tested class, db is opened but into test class i got error.

Comment: try adding `System.out.println("Testing insertTest - Length of testing List = " + String.valueOf(strings.size()));` as the first line in the `insertTest` method. i.e. to see if any data is being passed.

Comment: [this may be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960898/getting-context-in-androidtestcase-or-instrumentationtestcase-in-android-studio)