# androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry is deprecated

Tags: android, deprecated, androidx, android-testing

Switched to `AndroidX` and received deprecated: `import androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry`.

If I made next import: `import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry`
 I can't use `getContext()`.

Ex:
`val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`.

In `build.gradle`:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0-beta02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-beta02'
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` in the most cases from [`androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/platform/app/InstrumentationRegistry.html).

If you need the Application, you can use `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<MyAppClass>()`.

If you haven't already, I think you can also use the new test dependency:
`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0-beta02'`.

Comment: It's `InstrumentationRegistry` from `androix.test.platform.app` package

Comment: Comment from @woprandi fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: I've added "androidx.test:core:1.1.0" but I don't have access to ApplicationProvider. What do I miss? Thanks

Comment: @lorenzo see my answer

Answer (score 56):

When you're using Android X you need to make sure you have the following in your app's build.gradle file

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
```

The second one is to make sure you have the correct AndroidJUnit4 to use in your tests.

Make sure you import both of these.

```
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
```

Now instead of using `val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` you can use the line shown below

```
val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
```

Comment: I sincerely wonder why android studio projects using androidx don't come out of the box with the testing part up to date.

Comment: This is giving me "error: package androidx.test.platform.app does not exist"

Comment: This is the real trick to solve all of these contexts' version problem for androidX user.

Comment: @Mark O'Sullivan, I'm receiving the runtime error '_Unresolved reference: test_' on this line - `import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry`. This is within the **test** directory for a JUnit test.

Comment: Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57454390/2253682) to my issue above with the **import**. It was related to how the library dependency is added.

Comment: @Adam Hurwitz suggestion works to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So for anyone new to Android: make sure your test class is in the ANDROID test package, not the regular test package. That was the issue for me.

Comment: @Mark O'Sullivan this worked like magic for me Thanks !

Answer (score 13):

The following code is deprecated now:

```
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
```

Instead use:

```
Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: That gives "error: package androidx.test.core.app does not exist"

Comment: try to add     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'

Answer (score 8):

I spent a lot of time moving dependency with `testImplementation` instead of `androidTestImplementation` and reverse, in the app `build.gradle`.

My fault was that I have created the test class in the `test` folder instead of `androidTest` folder so getting unresolved error for `AndroidJuit4` and `InstrumentationRegistry`.

When I shifted my test file to the `androidTest` folder then issue been solved with depandency implementation of test libraries with `androidTestImplementation` in the `build.gradle`.

Comment: I don't know why you don't get more upvotes. This was the issue for me. In hindsight it's obvious, but when first doing Android testing it isn't obvious that the folder matters a lot.

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin usage, in order to get Context:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below import

```
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry

Kotlin ex
   InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context,
```

Comment: The import path is also the same for Java with SDK version 30.