# What's the difference between getTargetContext() and getContext (on InstrumentationRegistry)?

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm using the new Android Testing Support Library (`com.android.support.test:runner:0.2`) to run Instrumentation Tests
(a.k.a Device or Emulator Tests).

I annotate my test class with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` and use Android Studio to run them.

For my test cases I need a `Context` instance. I can get it with `InstrumentationRegistry` but it has two context related methods and it's not clear what the difference is.

What is the difference between `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` vs. `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> `InstrumentationRegistry` is an exposed registry
>   instance that holds a reference to the instrumentation running in the
>   process and it's arguments and allows injection of the following
>   instances:
>
> - `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()`, returns the
>     Instrumentation currently running.
> - `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`, returns the Context of this
>     Instrumentation’s package.
> - `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`,
>     returns the application Context of the target application.
> - `InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments()`, returns a copy of arguments
>     Bundle that was passed to this Instrumentation. This is useful when
>     you want to access the command line arguments passed to
>     Instrumentation for your test.

**EDIT:**

> So when to use getContext() vs getTargetContext()?

The documentation doesn't do a great job of explaining the differences so here it is from my POV:

You know that when you do instrumentation tests on Android then you have two apps:

1. The test app, that executes your test logic and tests your "real" app
2. The "real" app (that your users will see)

So when you are writing your tests and you want to load a resource *of your real app*, use `getTargetContext()`.

If you want to use a resource *of your test app* (e.g. a test input for one of your tests) then call `getContext()`.

Comment: So when to use `getContext()` vs `getTargetContext()`?

Comment: I just had to use `getContext()` because I was getting the wrong file from `openRawResource()`. I was trying to access a raw resource in the test package, `app/src/androidTest/res/raw`, but kept getting the wrong file when using `getTargetContext().getResources().openRawResource(com.example.test.R.raw.resource_name`.

Solution: `getContext().getResources().openRawResource(com.example.test.R.raw.resource_name` gave me the correct file.

Answer (score 2):

You may need `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` for access to raw resources of a test case.

E.g., to access `app/src/androidTest/res/raw/resource_name.json` in a TestCase:

`final Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(com.example.package.test.R.raw.resource_name);`

Answer (score 2):

Took me hours to find that out.

A InstrumentedTest case had a context member which was set up in the setup like this:

```
context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
```

this was used to open files, especially things like that:

```
String filenameOriginal = context.getCacheDir() + "/initial.csv";
```

Now I decided that I need to use some resource which is **only** available in the instrumented test, I did not want to distribute this resource with the release version.
Therefore I recreated the resource directories under test:

```
app\src\androidTest
└───res
    └───raw
            v1.csv
```

But to be able to use this in code I had to call something like this:

```
    public static Uri resourceToUri(Context context, int resID)
    {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                context.getResources().getResourcePackageName(resID) + '/' +
                context.getResources().getResourceTypeName(resID) + '/' +
                context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(resID));
    }

    resourceToUri(context, R.raw.v1)
```

Which would *always* fail because R.raw.v1 coincidently corresponded to something that was actually in my `R` resource file from the main application. By using resources in the instrumented tests, there were two `R` files generated. To fix that I had to include the test R file:

```
import com.my_thing.app.my_app.test.R;
```

the `resourceToUri` call would then however sill fail.

The issue was, that I must not have used `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` but rather`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext()` to get the resource of `R.raw.v1` so I blindly replace the setup of the context for the whole test class to

```
context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
```

It worked well for the specific test but other tests in the test case started to fail with permission denied for the `filenameOriginal` I was using above.

Turned out that by replacing the context to the instrumentation context I obtained a path to which my app had no access and I got `FileNotFoundException` with `permission denied` and no `GrantTestRule` or other things would work.

So be careful when using those contexts, it might screw your time :/

Comment: The `InstrumentationRegistry` class does not exist

Comment: @kurdtpage did you import it via `import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. There are two apps that are installed when ever you are doing instrumentation tests.

1. Target app: App you want to test[Your App]
2. Test app: App which has your testing logic.

In kotlin's world

`getInstrumentation().context` returns context of Test app
`getInstrumentation().targetContext` returns the context of Target app.