# Cannot find context in class which extends TestCase

Tags: java, android, android-testing, testcase

I am writing test cases for android app classes. But I am unable to find  a way to get context of this class. Below is my test case class.

```
public class SplashScreenActivityTest extends TestCase {
    SplashScreenActivity splashScreenActivity;
    Context context;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        splashScreenActivity = new SplashScreenActivity();
    }

    public void testDeviceDetailsPost() throws Exception {
     //I need to access a method here which requires context
    }
}
```

I looked through many questions but I cannot understand their answers.

For example this question 
[Get context of test project in Android junit test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605611/get-context-of-test-project-in-android-junit-test-case)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance variable `context` to the method that requires it as follows `methodThatRequiresContext(context);`

I'm not entirely sure what your difficulty is.

Comment: The context must contain a context just creating the variable and passing it to the method won't work.

Comment: like Context context = getContext();

Answer (score 0):

You can use AndroidTestCase, this class has method getContext();

Or create class without parent and add @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) to class header. And use this : InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

Reminder: i must put this test class to the androidTest package, because this classes there are integration tests.

Comment: AndroidTestCase is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Good starting points to understand testing for Android.

1. Training [Building effective unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/index.html) (official documentation from Google)
2. Repository [Android Testing Blueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint) contains examples for different kind of tests.